# images not showing in htaccess with multiple parameters?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a problem with .htaccess someone help me. here the following coding i used in .htaccees file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /sandbox/all_deals.php?city_id=$1&city_name=$2&cat_id=$3&cat_name=$4&deal_shop_id=$5&deal_shop_name=$6 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /sandbox/all_deals.php?city_id=$1&city_name=$2&cat_id=$3&cat_name=$4 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/(.*)/
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/ /sandbox/all_deals.php?city_id=$1&city_name=$2
```

When i use above coding images and background images are not showing

My domain url is like www.domain.com/sandbox

I wants the rewrite urls as following method.

```
 1) www.domain.com/sandbox/city-name/shop-name/cat-name/
 2) www.domain.com/sandbox/city-name/shop-name/ 
 3) www.domain.com/sandbox/city-name
```

I need all the above conditions should work.

i get the id values as

```
<?php $deal_shop_id= $_GET['deal_shop_id'];
      $cat_id      = $_GET['cat_id'];
      $city_id     = $_GET['city_id'];
?>
```

My folder structure is

```
/sandbox
/sandbox/images/
/sandbox/all_deals.php
/sandbox/css/style.css
```

Please some one help me to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Sat

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a relative URI base to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: i have added <base href="http://www.domain.com/sandbox/"> this in head tag and my image url is like  <img src="/images/logo/logo.png"/> but it is not showing

Comment: @satheesh If your image urls are `/images/logo/logo.png`, how do you expect it to know to go to the sandbox? You need to either change them all to relative URLs and use the `<base>` tag, or add a `/sandbox` in front of all of them.

Comment: i changed the Base URLs as like  <base href="http://www.domain.com/sandbox/" /> and css called as  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sandbox/css/style.css" media="all"/> and  image urls as <img src="/images/logo/logo.png" /> and background images in css as "background:url(../images/front_images/bg_green.jpg);". Still i didnt fix these. please give suggestion.

Comment: @satheesh `<base href="/sandbox/">`, change all your URLs so that they are relative. This means you remove the leading slash: `<img src="images/logo/logo.png">`, like I said in my previous comment.